# Проблема с конкатенацией Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Не могу произвести конкатенацию. Понимаю что дело в индексах. Не получается никак. Необходимо что бы индекс сохранился. Помогите пожалуйста.

df1:

```
2019-10-11 10:00:00    133870
2019-10-11 10:30:00    133800
2019-10-11 11:00:00    133680
2019-10-11 11:30:00    133650
```

df2:

```
2019-11-10 10:00:00    133330
2019-11-10 10:30:00    133850
2019-11-10 11:00:00    133600
2019-11-10 11:30:00    133650
```

После concat:

```
                      close      last            
datetime                               
2019-10-11 10:00:00  133870.0       NaN
2019-10-11 10:30:00  133800.0       NaN
2019-10-11 11:00:00  133680.0       NaN
2019-10-11 11:30:00  133650.0       NaN
2019-11-10 10:00:00       NaN  133330.0
2019-11-10 10:30:00       NaN  133850.0
2019-11-10 11:00:00       NaN  133600.0
2019-11-10 11:30:00       NaN  133650.0
```

Надо:

```
                      close      last            
datetime                               
2019-10-11 10:00:00  133870.0  133330.0
2019-10-11 10:30:00  133800.0  133850.0
2019-10-11 11:00:00  133680.0  133600.0
2019-10-11 11:30:00  133650.0  133650.0
```

Пробовал:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

df1.join(df2) и т.д.
```

Comment: Просто по порядку собрать вместе, игнорируя дату?

Comment: df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True) если так, то индекс не сохраняется

Comment: а что-нить типа `df1['last'] = df2['last'].values`

Comment: Не знаю почему но это работает df2.index = df1.index, далее df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

Comment: То что дата в `df1` - `2019-10-11`, а в `df2` - `2019-11-10` - это опечатка?

Comment: Это моя не внимательность. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Все заработало без всяких df2.index = df1.index